# R 文字型データから日時データへの変換

Tags: r, database

"2022.04.30 午前 5:55"
のような文字列データをRの日時データに変換したいです。
文字列を地道に置換していけば出来るような気もしなくはないですが、スマートなやり方をご存知でしたら教えて頂きたく。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
$ R

R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"

> strptime("2022.04.30 午前 5:55", format="%Y.%m.%d %p %I:%M", tz="JST")
[1] "2022-04-30 05:55:00 JST"
> strptime("2022.04.30 午後 5:55", format="%Y.%m.%d %p %I:%M", tz="JST")
[1] "2022-04-30 17:55:00 JST"
```